# How to receive multiple ATCommand response packets from the local xbee for the "FN" (finding neighbour) AT command using python digi-xbee library

Tags: python, xbee

This is the code which works well for all AT commands except "FN":

```
from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice

#Initialise a serial port for the local xbee 
local_xbee = XBeeDevice("/dev/tty.usbserial-AH02D9Q4", 9600). 

#Opens serial port for sending commands   
local_xbee.open()

#Sets new timeout for sync command operation 
local.set_sync_ops_timeout(10). 

#Send "FN" AT command to local xbee to receive neighbour list
neighbour_xbee_list = local.get_parameter("FN")

print(neighbour_xbee_list)

local_xbee.close()
```

## Note:

The above code returns only one neighbour whereas I have more than one nodes in the network.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the point of the question is not how to use the FN command, but how to discover neighbors.

For this, you can use the start_discovery_process function described here.
http://xbplib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_doc/discovering_the_xbee_network.html#discovernetwork

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply.
But the api's related to discovery process returns the lsit of all nodes present in the network whereas i need to know olny the immediate neighbours of the remote or local node to whom the AT Command "FN" was issued.

Comment: You might need to look into how `start_discovery_process` was implemented (it should be using the `ATND` command) and emulate that behavior for `ATFN`.  I'm not familiar with the framework, but you need to signal the library that `ATFN` is a multi-line response that's only complete when it receives a blank line from the XBee.

Answer (score 0):

```
import serial
from digi.xbee.packets.common import ATCommPacket
from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice
from digi.xbee.reader import PacketListener
from digi.xbee.serial import XBeeSerialPort
from digi.xbee.util import utils
import time


local_xbee = XBeeDevice("/dev/tty.usbserial-AH02D9Q4", 9600)
local_xbee.open()
print("This is : ", local_xbee.get_node_id())
print(local_xbee._packet_listener.is_running())
parameter = "FN"
frame_id = 33
my_packet = ATCommPacket(frame_id, parameter)
#print(my_packet)
#print(my_packet.frame_id)
#print(my_packet.command)
final_send = my_packet.output()
local_xbee._serial_port.write(final_send)
print("Finding Neighbours")
while True:
    print(".")
    Queue = local_xbee._packet_listener.get_queue()
    received_packet = Queue.get_by_id(frame_id)
    if received_packet != None:
        #if received_packet.status == ATCommandStatus.OK:
        final = received_packet._get_api_packet_spec_data().__str__()
        print(final)
    time.sleep(0.5)

local_xbee.close()
```

Comment: Using the logic implemented for start_discovery_process for finding all the nodes present in the network I have developed a logic to find immediate neighbours of Local XBee in the network.